# Unable to start second activity (problem with manifest)

Tags: java, android

I have 2 activities and I need to start `GameActivity` from `MainActivity`, but there's some problem with `AndroidManifest`. What should I write there?

Manifest:

```
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
        <activity android:name=".GameActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.ALTERNATIVE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

MainActivity:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btnStart:
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, GameActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 10);
                break;
            case R.id.btnExit:
                finish();
                break;
        }
    }
```

GameActivity

```
public class GameActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.btnBack:
                finish();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

xml activity_game

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".GameActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnBack"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:text="@string/btnBack" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="0"
            android:textSize="30dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <com.example.clicker.DrawView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Logcat message:

```
2019-04-06 22:00:00.914 10196-10196/com.example.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 10196
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapplication/com.example.myapplication.GameActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #33: Binary XML file line #33: Error inflating class com.example.clicker.DrawView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #33: Binary XML file line #33: Error inflating class com.example.clicker.DrawView
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #33: Error inflating class com.example.clicker.DrawView
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.clicker.DrawView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.myapplication-UnaaN19LjC_yTurW970Ruw==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.myapplication-UnaaN19LjC_yTurW970Ruw==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.myapplication-UnaaN19LjC_yTurW970Ruw==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.myapplication-UnaaN19LjC_yTurW970Ruw==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.myapplication-UnaaN19LjC_yTurW970Ruw==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.myapplication-UnaaN19LjC_yTurW970Ruw==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.myapplication-UnaaN19LjC_yTurW970Ruw==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.myapplication-UnaaN19LjC_yTurW970Ruw==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.myapplication-UnaaN19LjC_yTurW970Ruw==/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.myapplication-UnaaN19LjC_yTurW970Ruw==/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.myapplication-UnaaN19LjC_yTurW970Ruw==/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.myapplication-UnaaN19LjC_yTurW970Ruw==/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.myapplication-UnaaN19LjC_yTurW970Ruw==/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.myapplication-UnaaN19LjC_yTurW970Ruw==/lib/x86, /system/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:606)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
        at com.example.myapplication.GameActivity.onCreate(GameActivity.java:12)
2019-04-06 22:00:00.922 10196-10196/com.example.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
        Suppressed: java.io.IOException: No original dex files found for dex location /data/app/com.example.myapplication-UnaaN19LjC_yTurW970Ruw==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:354)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:101)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:75)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:394)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:354)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>(DexPathList.java:164)
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:74)
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
        at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.<init>(PathClassLoader.java:64)
        at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:73)
        at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:88)
        at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:74)
        at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:40)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:727)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:810)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(LoadedApk.java:1032)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2345)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5749)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:199)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1650)
                ... 6 more
        Suppressed: java.io.IOException: No original dex files found for dex location /data/app/com.example.myapplication-UnaaN19LjC_yTurW970Ruw==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:354)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:101)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:75)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:394)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:354)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>(DexPathList.java:164)
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:74)
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
        at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.<init>(PathClassLoader.java:64)
        at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:73)
        at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:88)
        at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:74)
        at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:40)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:727)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:810)
2019-04-06 22:00:00.923 10196-10196/com.example.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(LoadedApk.java:1032)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2345)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5749)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:199)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1650)
                ... 6 more
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem, and why do you think it has anything to do with the manifest? What error are you getting?

Comment: @Trushkeen what's the error. give logcat msg

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapplication/com.example.myapplication.GameActivity}:
I got this file classes without manifest file

Comment: @Trushkeen please provide a full stack trace. There dosen't seem to be anything wrong with the code you presented, so maybe the error is in GameActivity.java?

Comment: @LevM. updated in post

Comment: Your real error is `Error inflating class com.example.clicker.DrawView`

Comment: @Trushkeen It is error in GameActivity.java at 12th line not in manifest, So put that activity and xml file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem with your manifest.
`GameActivity` is started, but crashes when it is trying to load its layout.

There is a problem with a custom `View` you are trying to use in `GameActivity`.
Here is the relevant line in the stack trace:

```
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #33: Binary XML file line #33: Error inflating class com.example.clicker.DrawView
```

So, the question is: where is the `DrawView.java` file?

I suspect, you either didn't copy it, or you need to fix its package name in the layout xml file for `GameActivity`.

Note, the error says `com.example.clicker.DrawView` but your app package is `com.example.myapplication`.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it, the error was that i copied the files and forgot to rename package